# Alexa Skill Set to send Custom Directives to my alexa enabled device

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is it possible to create a alexa skill which sends back custom directives created by me back to my alexa enabled devices, so that I can parse them in responses and take action.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you mean?  Its hard to tell if you just need a lot of intent samples or a long, custom slot list.  In either case, you can get to some very rich responses.

Comment: I have enabled alexa on rpi and there are other services also running on the  rpi. Now I want to invoke/control  those local services through alexa. Normally in a smart home skill you need to interface AVS with a skill adaptor which will control your IoT device. Is it possible to directly send some custom directive/text/string in the http response to rpi which I can parse and take action accordingly. Like I say to alexa "Start service1", then I get a response with "service1" in any field which I can use to invoke service1 on rpi

Comment: I don't know if there is any such kind of feature currently supported by AVS or not

Answer (score 0):

In your example, Alexa start service1, service1 becomes the invocation (e.g. skill) name.  This is fixed as one per skill.  So, you can what you've explicitly requested.  Some additional info that may be helpful:

As for other content after the invocation, it isn't clear there is a mode to get the Echo to recognize anything.  I've heard some suggest providing very large intent sample lists or long slot dictionaries and it convinces the system to provide a more open recognition, but I've never seen that behavior myself.

If you list of items can be constrained, you can create multiple skills.  For a personal, aka developer setup, this works well.  I have multiple echos on the same account.  I have two defined skills that route to the same ASK service layer on my PI.  The launch URL routes the request into two different paths that are parsed on my NodeJS logic setting up different defaults in my code.

This allows my wife's version of the skill to work differently than mine.  We just use different invocation names without having to have separate accounts and implementing oAuth.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is old but I just spotted it while searching something else.  In case you have not solved it, the answer is yes.  I use my Rpi with Alexa this way.  If you are publishing a skill you need to use proper security measures that include account linking, Oauth2 etc. and there are limits on the types of commands you can accept without a user PIN.  However, if you are willing to assume the risk on a skill for your own use in developer mode, you can put http calls, with or without basic authentication, directly into your skill code as though it were any other public ip address.  As long as your pi is addressable from outside via http, you can command it.  I use my pi with a web server to control a media center.  I was sending Alexa commands to that via smart things, but now also have developed a custom skill to go straight fro Alexa tot he Pi and to link commands together.  I can say "Alexa, start listening..." and then send multiple menu commands via voice that are recognized by the Pi and executed (e.g. menu, guide, page down, channel name, select, etc...) until I exit or it times out due to no input.  I don't have to repeat "Alexa" or "turn on/off" as though each command were a device as is the case when going through smart things.  I would only recommend this if your htpc and pi have no secure data and are firewalled from the rest of your network.